# Jmeter Gradle Plugin Fail to Generate report

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jmeter, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I get the following exception when running the JMeter Gradle task in Jenkins. Do you guys know a fix for this ?

- gradle 6.5
- net.foragerr.jmeter:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.1.0-4.0
- jdk 11

https://pastebin.com/Qh493JKV

```
    > Task :jmInit
    > Task :jmRun FAILED

    > Task :jmReport
    There are no results file to create reports from
    Can't transform result
   groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils#copy.
   Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.io.FileOutputStream] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class java.io.InputStream, class java.io.OutputStream]
```

Comment: It looks to me like your JMeter run task (`jmRun`) failed, which is very likely why there are no results files to generate reports from. You will need to investigate why the run task failed in the first place, e.g. by following the advice given in the output you pasted:

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':jmRun'.
   > There were test errors.  See the jmeter logs for details.

Comment: Anybody got an Answer to this Question?
The jmRun task is not failing in my System and Successfully generating CSV files with Summary Report